# While sending from java,GCM push notificatios are not working

Tags: java, android

While sending GCM push notifications from java , i am getting following response.

> {"multicast_id":8802417572032089725,"success":0,"failure":5,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}.

Here is my code :

```
PostMethod post = null;
    try
    { // Below is a good tutorial , how to post json data
      // http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

        String url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
        HttpClient httpclient = getHttpClient();
        post = new PostMethod(url);
        JSONObject mainData = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.putOpt("message", "my message");
            data.putOpt("title", "My title");
            JSONArray regIds = new JSONArray();
            for (String s : registrationIds)
            {
                regIds.put(s);
            }
            mainData.put("registration_ids", regIds);
            mainData.put("data", data);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            LOG.info(e.getCause(), e);
        }
        post.setRequestBody(mainData.toString());
        post.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "key=" + googleApiKey);

        post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpclient.executeMethod(post);
        String response = new String(post.getResponseBody());

        LOG.info("Response body of Mobile No :  "+ mobileNo + "  is : " +response);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        LOG.info(e.getCause(), e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOG.info(e.getCause(), e);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(post != null)
        {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error clearly indicates, do you have valid sender id?

Comment: Simze: Yes ,I have sender ID which is generated by My android team .Do i need to send Sender Id also along with API key? Sorry i forget to mention ,some of users getting notifications.

Comment: @AnandSavjani I did not get your answer.

Comment: @sumantipparapu : sorry it was my mistake . Please refer this. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream

Comment: Thanks guys, its resolved. Actually the problem with Registration ids.

Comment: But I have another question .Can i send attachment in notifications?